# Maven multiple modules hierarchy

Tags: maven, multi-module

I'm not sure how to structure my multiple-module Maven project. Basically, I have 4 different modules.

1. `main` module
2. `input-handler` module
3. `output-handler` module
4. `utils` module

Modules `input-handler` and `output-handler` mostly use the same dependencies - some I/O libraries, JUnit libraries, DI libraries etc.

`utils` module is the module I have developed as the supporting module for all of the other 3 of my modules, and each of them should be able to see it.

Lastly, `main` module behaves like the driver module. It should include both `input-handler` and the `output-handler` and coordinate them in runtime to achieve the general functionality.

My idea was to make `main` the parent project and then `output-handler` and `input-handler` as its submodules, this way they would inherit some shared dependencies - but then `main` should include its own submodules in order to use them - which seems like a circular dependency problem.

What would be the correct structure for this?

Comment: I would structure them as 4 submodules and main should import input and output handler, and input and output handler should each import utils

Comment: @aurelius 4 submodules of some root? So overall you'd have 5 modules in that design?

Comment: one project with 4 submodules

Answer (score 1):

Put your modules in one folder (this will be the parent project) then create a pom.xml file in this folder, the content should looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>parent-project-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>utils</module>
        <module>input-handler</module>
        <module>output-handler</module>
        <module>main</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

After that you can run  `mvn clean install` in the parent project folder and your modules will be compiled in he order you want.